# How to make concrete implementation of an interface not accessible outside the scope of the library.?

Tags: android, kotlin, aar

I'm working on developing an Android library. I want to make a few classes inaccessible to the users who implement my library. Mostly the interface realization classes. For instance, I have the following classes in moduleA,

- Animal ( interface )
- Dog ( Realization of Animal interface )
- AnimalProvider ( Object that helps to initialize Animal object from the activity/any view )

Since I'm using Kotlin I made `Dog` an internal class to make it inaccessible outside the library scope. But, the problem is `AnimalProvider` is an object that has a public function called `getAnimalSource()`. Something like this,

```
object AnimalProvider {
 fun getAnimalSource(
 context: Context, 
 lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner
 ) = Dog( context = Context, lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner)
```

And it's throwing an error like,

`public function exposes its internal return type`.

I need this function to initialize the `Animal` object from the activity/view. Am I approaching the issue in the right direction.? Or, what's the proper way to hide concrete classes when you publish an android library.?

Comment: Try `fun getAnimalSource(context: Context, lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner): Animal = Dog(context, lifecycleOwner)`. IOW, explicitly set the return type of `getAnimalSource()` to be `Animal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it implicitly declares the return type of `getAnimalSource()` to be `Dog`, and `Dog` is `internal`.

You need to hide that type, by explicitly declaring the return type of `getAnimalSource()`:

```kotlin
object AnimalProvider {
 fun getAnimalSource(
 context: Context, 
 lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner
 ): Animal = Dog( context = Context, lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner)
```

Now, `getAnimalSource()` is declared to return an `Animal`, not a `Dog`, and you should be in better shape.